# How to use ClientPeoplePicker in JSOM

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am creating a SharePoint-hosted app. I want to utilize `<SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker>` control but I am struggling with being able to read the user entered value in one of my `App.js` functions.

Here is highlighted part of the `Default.aspx` code:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
...
<asp:TableCell>
  <SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker ID="PMPeoplePicker" runat="server" Required="true" PrincipalAccountType="User" AllowMultipleEntities="false" ValidationEnabled="true" />          
</asp:TableCell>
...
```

And here is the part of the `App.js` code where I want to read the value from the control:

```
function getPM() {
  // This is obviously not working ...
  var pm = $("#PMPeoplePicker");
  return pm;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this MSDN How To: Use the client-side People Picker control in SharePoint-hosted apps

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593(v=office.15).aspx

And demo code Microsoft provided

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2013-Add-the-900e0742

Comment: Thanks @Ken, that helps. The truth is that I came across this article myself which does solve my question, however, since the `<SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker>` is replace with the `initializePeoplePicker` method, I am finding it hard to resolve the validation on the control (required field, entered user text is resolved, one user only, no groups allowed), as I am starting with plain `<div>` in the example provided. Have you dealt with validation? Thanks.